# Socket Char Array being appended

Tags: c++, sockets

String variable and char variable **cout** more than once as seen in the image. I have **ZeroMem() buff** How can I normalize it so it couts "Invader Said: Reddit" **Instead** of "Invader Said: RedditInvader Reddit".

```
char buff[4096];
string serverMessage = "GET OUT MY SERVER!";

while (true) {
    ZeroMemory(buff, 4096);

    int bytesRecived = recv(clientSocket, buff, 4096, 0);

    if (bytesRecived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Error in recv()! Qutting!" << endl;
    }

    if (bytesRecived == 0) {
        cout << "Client Disconnected" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << "Invader Said: " << buff;
    send(clientSocket, (char*)serverMessage.c_str(), serverMessage.length(), 0);
}
```

[image: Problem Visualized]

Comment: Images of text are not helpful. Use your copy-paste-fu to show text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the characters send by the other side will all be sent in one message. So on the PuTty side, when the user types `Reddit`<kbd>return</kbd> we don't know exactly how all this data will be sent over the net.

Your screenshot looks different from your narrative becasue ther's no seccond Reddit:

```
Invader said: RedditInvader said:
```

Here is what I understand based on it.

At the first loop:

- You'll receive 6 chars at once
- no error, so the first `if` body isn't executed
- no empty buffer, so the second `if` body isn't executed.
- You print `Invader said:`, followed by the chars received `Reddit`
- You send back to Putty a first message

The loop continues.  At the second iteration:

- Your receive the equivalent of the <kbd>return</kbd> (1 or 2 chars that when printed out look like a newline)
- no error, so the first `if` body isn't exectuted
- no empty buffer, so the second `if` body isn't exectuted.
- You print `Invader said:`, followed by the chars received, which look like a newline
- You send back to Putty a second message

I can't tell more (breakpoint ? or `recv()` still waiting because you didn't  <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> ? ...)

That's the only explanation.  If you would have received all the PuTty chars at once, you would get a different output:

```
Invader said: Reddit
Invader said:              (or something else, but on a new line)
```

*Remark 1: it's not linked to your problem, but if you encounter an error, your programme will keep trying to print output and looping, because you didn't foresee a `break` in this case*

*Remark 2: it's not linked either, but if you receive exactly 4096 chars at once, your output might cause UB, because there would be a missing null terminator at the end of the buffer*

Could be of interest for you:

- [Problem with the recv caused by end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39437199/3723423)
- [Problem because recv calls do not match one to one with send calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35542760/3723423)
- [Similar problem, but with an example of reassembling data received by several recv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214272/3723423).  You could adapt this to process only full lines (i.e. until a newline is received).

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `buff` as if it were a null terminated string, but socket data is not null terminated. If you *happened* to receive exactly 4096 bytes, your use of `operator<<` would exceed the bounds of the array. You must take the return value of `recv()` into account when using `buff`.

Same with `send()`. It may return fewer bytes than requested, so you have to look at the return value and potentially have to call it again to resend more data.

Try this instead:

```
char buff[4096];
const string serverMessage = "GET OUT MY SERVER!";
bool keepLooping = true;

while (keepLooping) {
    int bytesRecived = recv(clientSocket, buff, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesRecived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Error in recv()! Qutting!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    if (bytesRecived == 0) {
        cout << "Client Disconnected" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << "Invader Said: ";
    cout.write(buff, bytesRecived);
    cout << endl;

    const char *ptr = serverMessage.c_str();
    size_t len = serverMessage.length();
    do {
        int bytesSent = send(clientSocket, ptr, len, 0);
        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cerr << "Error in send()! Qutting!" << endl;
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        }
        ptr += bytesSent;
        len -= bytesSent;
    }
    while (len > 0);
}
```